# Calling external contract running out of gas?

Tags: solidity, remix

hope you can assist.

I have this very basic template setup, where contract `TokenVote` should simply store some data on the `SimpleStore` contract (Sort of eternal storage)

Yet my code always runs out of gas. What's wrong with my approach?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ABSTRACTING {
    function addToWhitelist(address _ad) public;
}

contract SimpleStore {

    address[] public UserList;

    function addToWhitelist(address _ad) public {
        UserList.push(_ad);
    }
}

contract TokenVote {

    ABSTRACTING tokenContract;

    constructor(address token) public {
        tokenContract = ABSTRACTING(token);
    }

    function doStuff () public  {
        tokenContract.addToWhitelist(msg.sender);
    }

}
```

Comment: To begin with, change `contract ABSTRACTING` to `interface ABSTRACTING` and `contract SimpleStore` to `contract SimpleStore is ABSTRACTING`.

Comment: BTW, AFAIK, the `constructor` keyword is supported from `solidity 0.4.21` onward, while you seem to be on `solidity 0.4.18`.

Comment: This exact code runs fine for me in Remix. I deployed `SimpleStore` first, then passed the resulting address to the constructor when creating `TokenVote`, and then I called `doStuff`. My gas limit was set to 3,000,000 for all transactions.

Comment: @smarx You're right. In remix it works. Somehow on EthFiddle it runs out of gas. Damm.

Comment: I see the same error on EthFiddle, but I don't see a good way to debug.

Comment: Getting back to this. On Javascript VM there is no issue with the code, but when running on local node it reverts back. Gas limit on ganache is set at 9.000.000 and still reverting. Switch to JS, no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - It seems to be a bug in Ethfiddle.

@smarx pointed out that it worked in Remix without issues.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some ways to check and overcome the problem:

check if you really need everything you inherit
put a higher gasLimit to your truffle.js config, try gas: 7492052, which is higher than the value in Truffle's defaults, and than in Rinkeby testnet.
use optimizer settings to make bytecode slimmer and deploy cheaper
if the above doesn't let you deploy and at least see your actual deploy cost, try commenting some functionality out and trying local deploy without something
if the steps above show that you really need this much code and more, you can chop it in parts and deploy some of it as libraries or as separated contracts, one addressing another, depending on what fits you best.
Hope it helps, that's basically my own trial-and-error conspectus on the matter.